# How to log parameter that's not yet available for the layout renderer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, logging, nlog

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC application that has NLog set up as its logger. I'm not too familiar with its set up, but we have an `nlog.config` where we set up our parameter names that we log and the layout renderers for them that get the values. We use `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;` to inject an instance of `ILogger` into our controller actions and service methods throughout the application.

When we, for example, log something like `_logger.LogInformation("Client was created");`, along with other pieces of data, we log the name of the authenticated user. This is the `ObjectID` in the code below, the value of which is taken from `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

The problem is that I want to log the ObjectID at a point where it's not yet available in `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`. This results in a log record without an ObjectID. However, the ObjectID is available in another variable.

Is there a way to log a message and pass the value of a parameter instead of having the logger get it from the layout renderer? I do still want it to use the layout renderer if I'm not passing the parameter manually.

Relevant part of `nlog.config`:

```
<commandText>
  insert into dbo.Log (
  CorrelationId, Application, ObjectID, Logged, Level, Message,
  Logger, CallSite, Exception
  ) values (
  @CorrelationId, @Application, @ObjectID, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
  @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception
  );
</commandText>
<parameter name="@correlationId" layout="${aspnet-traceidentifier}" />
<parameter name="@application" layout="${configsetting:AppSettings.NlogConnection.AppName}" />
<parameter name="@ObjectID" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" /> <!-- I want to be able to optionally pass the value of this parameter manually -->
<parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
<parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
<parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
<parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
<parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite:filename=false}" />
<parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:toString}" />
```

How we inject and use the logger instance:

```
public class ClientService : IClientService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ClientService> _logger;

    public ClientService(ILogger<ClientService> Logger)
    {
        _logger = Logger;
    }

    public string CreateClient() {
        //some logic to create client
        string userName = "John Doe"; // I want to log this as ObjectID in the database
        _logger.LogInformation("Client created");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make use of whenEmpty, so when the Identity.Name provided using `${event-properties}` fails then fallback to `${aspnet-user-identity}`. Ex.: `${event-properties:ObjectID:whenEmpty=${aspnet-user-identity}}`. See also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/WhenEmpty-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. As I understand it, it will only use the `event-properties:ObjectID` if I provide it through structured logging? Also, I'm a bit confused about the syntax. Are the additional `${}` characters surrounding `asp-user-identity` necessary? If they are, why aren't they around `event-properties` either?

Comment: Yes you can do this: `_logger.LogInformation("Client created {ObjectID}", userName);`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging

Comment: Great! Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add properties](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging) like his:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Client created {ObjectID}", userName);
```

And configure `@ObjectId`-parameter using [whenEmpty](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/WhenEmpty-Layout-Renderer) like this:

```
<parameter name="@ObjectID" layout="${event-properties:ObjectID:whenEmpty=${aspnet-user-identity}}" />
```